# Progress Bar Sizing

Tags: css, geometry, progress-bar, height, width

I am attempting to size the progress bar to be 300px x 300px but it keeps cutting off the top of the circle and the text at the bottom.

It should look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this after my code:

[image]

What should I adjust based on my code? Have tried to adjust the height and width of multiple containers but still no luck.:

```css
#progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 55%;
  transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .card:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.percent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #000;
  background: #222;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.percent .number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.percent .number h2 {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .percent .number h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.percent .number h2 span {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #777;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .percent .number h2 span {
  color: #fff;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

svg circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #191919;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: translate(5px, 5px);
}

svg circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
}

.card:nth-child(1) svg circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dashoffset: calc( 440 - (440 * 90) / 100);
  /* use to adjust progress bar */
  stroke: #00ff43;
}
```

```html
<div id="feedbox-mid">
  <div id="progress-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="percent">
            <svg>
                      <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                      <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                    </svg>
            <div class="number">
              <h2>90<span>%</span></h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h2 class="text">Html</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I increased the width and height in .container .card. to 400px each.